# Reducer not working in Hadoop Mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hi My Reducer is not printing the desired result please have a look at the code.

This is my map function

```
public  void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {   

            String str_line = value.toString();
            Detail_output1_column_array = str_line.split("\\"+tabSpace);


            Outputkey = Detail_output1_column_array[2];
            System.out.println(Outputkey);
            context.write(new Text(Outputkey),NullWritable.get());
        }
    }

    public  static class ShopFile_Reducer extends Reducer<Text,Iterable<NullWritable>,NullWritable,Text> {


        public void reduce(Text Key,Iterable<NullWritable> Values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {



            Key = new Text(Key.toString());
            context.write(NullWritable.get(),new Text(Key));

        }

    }
```

Suppose Detail_output1_column_array[2] contains
01
01
01
02
01
02
01
03
01

After reducer I need the output like this
01
02
03

But it is printing every thing
01
01
01
02
01
02
01
03
01

This is my driver class

```
Configuration Shopconf = new Configuration();
        Shopconf.setStrings("DTGroup_input",DTGroup_input);
        Job Shop = new Job(Shopconf,"Export_Column_Mapping");
        Shop.setJarByClass(ExportColumnMapping.class);
        Shop.setJobName("ShopFile_Job");
        Shop.setMapperClass(ShopFile_Mapper.class);
        Shop.setReducerClass(ShopFile_Reducer.class);
        Shop.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        Shop.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        Shop.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        Shop.setMapOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
        Shop.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        Shop.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(Shop, new Path(outputpath+"/Detailsfile/part*"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(Shop, new Path(outputpath+"/Shopfile"));
        Shop.waitForCompletion(true);
```

Comment: 01 01 01 02 01 02 01 03 01 .... is this a single value or map outputs of various input lines ?

Comment: What your input format ? In your code snippet, you mapper actually writes `<"01 01 01 02 01 02 01 03 01", NullWritable>` to reducer, it should write `<"01", NullWritable>`, `<"01", NullWritable>`, `<"02", NullWritable>` instead.

Comment: it is the map inputs of various lines in input file @madhu.

Comment: can you print the key variable in reducer using system.out.println and let us know the exact results

Comment: @user2018791 no ,maper out put is as you expect <"01", NullWritable>,<"01", NullWritable>,

Comment: @madhu :yeah i tried it but it is not getting printed the logs..Thats the reason  i came to a conclusion -Reducer is not getting triggered,however i am getting mapper output written in part-r-* files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mapper code
use this `Outputkey.set( Detail_output1_column_array[2]);` instead of  `Outputkey = Detail_output1_column_array[2];`

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake in line

```
 Detail_output1_column_array = str_line.split("\\"+tabSpace);
```

It seems that the string split not working correctly. If you want to split it by tab and space you should change it to

```
Detail_output1_column_array = str_line.split("( |\\t)");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration can you make the below change and check

Instead of this line

```
 Shop.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
```

Add this line

```
Shop.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
```

Comment: I tried still it is not producing the desired result

Answer (score 0):

OK. So I don't know what is exactly wrong there. You code is working for me.

my data:

```
bash-4.1$ hdfs dfs -cat input/numbers
a   01
b   01
a   01
a   02
a   01
a   02
a   01
a   03
a   01
```

The output:

```
bash-4.1$ hdfs dfs -cat output/part-r-00000
01
02
03
```

Your code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class HdfsFiles {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://namenode:9000");
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
    job.setJarByClass(HdfsFiles.class);
    job.setJobName("myjob");
    job.setMapperClass(ShopFile_Mapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(ShopFile_Reducer.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("input"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("output"));

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }

  static class ShopFile_Mapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, NullWritable> {
    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String str_line = value.toString();
      context.write(new Text(str_line.split("\\t")[1]), NullWritable.get());
    }
  }

  static class ShopFile_Reducer extends Reducer<Text, Iterator<NullWritable>, NullWritable, Text> {
    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Iterator<NullWritable>> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      context.write(NullWritable.get(), key);
    }
  }
}
```